# Python 3.2.2 READ from console

Tags: python, console, python-3.x

I am working on Python 3.2.2. The user has the option of entering the value on the console or let the default value be used if he just hits ENTER. e.g. If the user hits ENTER, the value is set to c:\temp as shown in code snippet below:

```
READ=os.read(0,100)
if READ == "\n" :
  READ="c:\\temp"
```

This code used to work in python 2.7, but it does not work on python 3.2.2.

In 3.2.2, the READ remains empty.
Any suggestions please to improve this code?

Comment: might be helpful to tell why it doesn't work...

Comment: Why `os.read(0, 100)` instead of just `input()`?

Comment: In such cases, you should be capable of working it out; to start with, `print(repr(READ))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `os.read` returns `class str` in python 2.7, but `class bytes` in python 3.2. So in python 3.2, `if READ == "\n": READ="C:\\temp"` will **never** be `True`. You may change like this:

```
if str(READ,"ascii") == os.linesep: READ = "C:\\temp"
```

Maybe, more exactly:

```
import os,sys
READ = os.read(0,100)
if str(READ,sys.stdin.encoding) == os.linesep:
   READ = "C:\\temp"
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to `os.linesep`.

Comment: Thanks very much. 
"if str(READ,"ascii") == os.linesep" worked.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 made [changes in string handling](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit), so `os.read()` returns binary string.

Code should be fixed with

```
if READ == b'\n' :
  READ="c:\\temp"
```